# jQuery deleting table rows not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to delete table rows (TR) that contains a class named `item` from a range.

From the example:

```
<table id='theTable'>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='item'>
            <td>Google</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='item'>
            <td>Microsoft</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='item'>
            <td>Apple</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Obama</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='item'>
            <td>USA</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So the `John` has 3 items: `Google`, `Microsoft` and `Apple`. In the other side, `Obama` only have an item called `USA`.

That said, it means that `John` **starts at** the position of 0 and it **ends at** the position of 3 (which is when the item class ends).

What I'm trying to do is to delete the TR which has the `class item` in the range. So if I say my `start_index` starts at the position of 0 (which is where `John` starts) it should delete from the position of 1 until 3.

My problem is that only the first line of item is deleted.

[Here's a JSFiddle that illustrates my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/NYsBw/).

Comment: why don't u try `$("#theTable tr.item").remove()`

Comment: Can you change the HTML? If so, I'd recommend using a definition list:

`<dl><dt>John</dt><dd>google</dd><dd>Microsoft</dd><dd>Apple</dd></dl>`

Comment: do you need to remove rows given the person name? or for all people ?

Comment: I said I need to delete the `tr` in a range. Then I said that if my start_index **starts** at the position of 0 (which in this case is where `John` starts) it should delete all the tr with the class `item` until he finds a `tr` that **does not have** the class `item`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/NYsBw/6/)

It can take a selector to stop at, so just pass in that you want it to go through the siblings until they do `:not()` have the class `.item`. The whole thing then shrinks down to -

```
var start_index = 1;
$("#theTable>tbody>tr").eq(start_index - 1).nextUntil(":not(.item)").remove();
```

Though, your information would be semantically better if it was structured as nested elements if the `.item` is truly a collection related to the preceding row.

[edit - although if you only want the index to relate to the non-`.items` then use the following]

```
var start_index = 1;
$("#theTable>tbody>tr:not(.item)").eq(start_index - 1).nextUntil(":not(.item)").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

look at the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NYsBw/5/), this should meet what you need

```
/*
  The possibilities for the start_index are:
      1) - John
      2) - Obama
      3) - Roma
*/
var start_index = 3
    current_index = 0;


$("#theTable > tbody > tr").each(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('item') === false) {
        current_index++;
    } else if(current_index == start_index && $(this).hasClass('item')) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but @Klors solution is way more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

This will do just that. It will remove every tr that has class 'item' from your table.

```
$('#theTable tr.item').remove()
```

Comment: Read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

your condition was slightly wrong, instead of checking next inside of a nested condition, you could just wait for the next element and check it.

 also, the `.each()` function accepts 2 vars one for Index and other for Value.

 here is your <kbd>**[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/NYsBw/4/)**</kbd>

```
/*
  The possibilities for the start_index are:
      1) - John
      2) - Obama
      3) - Roma
*/
var start_index = 1;

$(function () {
    $("#theTable > tbody > tr").each(function (_idx, _val) {

        if (_idx >= start_index) {
            console.log(_idx);
            if ($(this).hasClass('item')) {
                $(this).remove();
            } else {
                // Stops the loop
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: give it a try with start_index = 3, this should remove items for roma!!!

start_index isn't the 'item' index but is for 'parent' (like john - obama - roma)

Comment: oh right, didnt notice it thanks. ill fix it in a bit